# Trouble understanding inheritance and implementing it in classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I am having trouble understanding inheritance and implementing it in classes. I am trying to create a program with the Reptile class as the base.

What's the best way to do this with the following data?

There will also be a menu class using what I think should be a switch case to select the desired reptile and display the information.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: Base on that data, the best way is without inheritance.

Comment: If you're the same guy who posted about cars earlier, this seems to suffer from the same problem: your data is the same in all cases - by being able to represent it as a chart like this where all fields are filled for all entries, it shows that the data can be represented in the same way.

Comment: If you need an example of things that benefit from inheritance, consider "Vehicle" as your base class. Then think about different kinds of vehicles: car, train, plane, helicopter, bicycle, ship.

Comment: @John I suspect that these are two different posters given the same homework task with different details.

Comment: @Zohar If that's the case, the lecturer should maybe give better real-world examples. It seems a little counterproductive to expect students to find a use for inheritance in a situation that doesn't benefit from it. Not a lot anyone can do about that though, I guess. +1 for your answer :)

Comment: @John Well I suspect that this is one of those gradual things - first you learn the concept of inheritance (the fact that a derived class is a specific type of it's base class) and then you learn what it's good for. I personally agree with you - I think that this is a poor way to teach, but hey, I'm not the one writing the syllabus...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I understand that this is some kind of homework exercise, since in the real world you will not use inheritance for this at all.

using the the image you posted, let me try to explain inheritance in the simplest terms I can.

You can think of a base class for all reptiles - Let's call it `Reptile`.
This class contains all the different aspects shared by all reptiles - things like preferred food, feeding time, food to weight ratio etc'.
All of these aspects can be coded as properties of the `Reptile` class.

Please note that in the real world, the `Species` and `ReptileType` would also be properties of the `Reptile` class, making the use if inheritance completely redundant in this case - But then again, we are not talking about real world applications yet - so:

A `Snake` is a specific type of `Reptile`. A `Lizard` is another specific type of `Reptile` - so let's create classes for those two types. 
So far, we have the `Reptile`, `Snake` and `Lizard` classes, where the last two inherits the first.
Moving on, a `Cobra` is a specific type of `Snake`, so is a `Rattlesnake`. So let's create classes for them inheriting from `Snake`. Much the same, a `BeardedLizard` is a specific type of `Lizard`, and so is a `Chameleon` - so here are another two classes to create.

So basically, I think your teacher is expecting to see the following:

```
class Reptile {/* implementation here */}
    class Snake : Reptile {/* implementation here */}
        class Cobra : Snake {/* implementation here */}
        class Rattlesnake: Snake {/* implementation here */}
    class Lizard: Reptile {/* implementation here */}
        class BeardedLizard : Lizard {/* implementation here */}
        class Chameleon : Lizard {/* implementation here */}
```

Now, the reason inheritance does not make sense in this situation, is that a `Snake` does not add any new capabilities to a `Reptile`, nor does a `Chameleon` to a `Lizard`. For inheritance to make sense, you will need to add new capabilities in the deriving types, that is specific to that class (and it's inheritors) and is not shared with the base class or any other inheritance chain of that class.

For instance, all snakes crawl, while all lizards walk. If you where to add a `Crawl()` method to the `Snake` class and a `Walk()` method to the `Lizard` class - Than it would make sense for a `Snake` and a `Lizard` class inheriting the `Reptile` class.